# Bounds on spectral norm of difference of powers of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, operator-norms

Given bounded linear operators $A$ and $B$, with $||A-B||<\epsilon$, what is the tightest upper bound on $||A^n-B^n||$, for positive integer $n$? Additionally, for my specific situation, $A$ is self-adjoint and $B$ is constructed as an approximation to $A$ via a linear combination of unitary operators.

Comment: if everything that we know is $\|A-B\|<\epsilon$, we can not estimate even $\|A^2-B^2\|$ even for real numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a bound in terms of $||A||$ and $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding $(B + (A-B))^n - B^n$ and taking norms gives $$\lVert A^n - B^n \rVert \le (\lVert B \rVert + \epsilon)^n - \lVert B \rVert^n = n \epsilon \lVert B \rVert^{n-1} + O(\epsilon^2) \; .$$
This is tight: consider any real $A, B$ with $0 < B < A$.

Comment: It should be $n\epsilon \|B\|^{n-1}$ really.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Of course! I've added the fix. Thanks!

Comment: Can lack of commutativity cause problems? For example, writing down $A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+B^{n-1})+D(C^{n-1}-D^{n-1})+(D-C)D^{n-1}$ seems to give extra factors of $n\epsilon||B||^{n-1}$.

Comment: @user47207 Lack of commutativity is no problem. E.g., letting $E = A-B$, $$\lVert (B+E)^3 - B^3 \rVert = \lVert B^2 E + EBE + EB^2 + BE^2 + EBE + E^2 B + E^3\rVert \le 3 \lVert B \rVert^2 \lVert E \rVert + 3 \lVert B \rVert \lVert E \rVert^2 + \lVert E \rVert^3.$$ In other words, you only need the norms to commute, which of course they do.